# how to create a base64encoded string from image resource

Tags: php, gdlib

I have sent a base64 encoded string via AJAX to PHP and created an image resource with `imagecreatefromstring` - all is fine.

Now I want to get the base64 encoded string after resizing te image, but i CANT find a function to get the base64encoded string.

Comment: @mishu of course... i tried base64encode($imageres) and even ob_contents etc. but it doesnt work...

Comment: You can use [resample](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29250930/4058484) to get the base64 encoded string after resizing

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Taken from http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php#93393

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring($file);

// start buffering
ob_start();
imagepng($image);
$contents =  ob_get_clean();

echo "<img src='data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode($contents)."' />";

imagedestroy($image);
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm sure i tried this before! Now it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: @netzafin: I know that feeling ;)

Comment: [According to the manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) `$contents = ob_get_clean();`  is a one-liner for what `ob_get_contents` and `ob_end_clean` does.