# Rotate Base64 Image String without saving image

Tags: php, png, base64

I get a response from the Fedex Shipping API which includes a PNG base64 image, however the image is coming vertically. I would like to rotate this image 90 degrees without saving it to the disk, and just display it in the browser for further printing.

I tried decoding the string first then rotating it using

```
$rotate_image = imagerotate($image, 90, 0);
echo "<img src=\"data:image/PNG;base64,".$image."\" alt=\"Label\" />";
```

But I've had no luck!!

Sample Image String

```
$image = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAyAAAASwAQAAAAAryhMIAAAml0lEQVR42u3d328jyZ0Y8Gr3Qb0HbKZ9yEMoQGDZ2ADzOmsBFw3CY/lg4PJ2+54XSxhHfNVCCY6EaXbTMkQHWIwSzIsETNh/Q+CHPMVDmc7SgwjTAfJwMZy7aS4n7BcD29wOstXYmqp8q7tJkRQpUSSb3p0teqxfS/VHXT++9f0WmyQSG7ghhShEIV8jhNa0MKi6fogE1/yQFEnyH6OAYL9La7gR8T3j5i+f+OEjkxo00BERbp2RINDDYA7i5VHYKnQAsTjyw+I1UjT9VlAw9dkI3PeRQfUhEpitIz30rNlI52n12N0BpEh4tRQWq07yHwch63SunuQ6uwNGPr/xu7zgh7u9aPCFReCvOnN6nTNCen0yG3Ff1Y6dT9rQUITXSmGBpUg3fOs3mqWLfqXLiHsTgfvuhlGUIKbj+w4mbfc25OolII78xcdD5KUfiYcx8jKaj7AY4R8R38cOeTYPcfq1Y8IkchH/4hD5/ZsKLvEnuU8rv4+IcxOx/BEScvcDNySC/ErMRaohYVcJsq8/jNK/OvL2TJ8fFR5UonAGIkxPl4hPABGuFiPhfASliMOr+7o+Qnq5js8CifjkxU2kDkgvRuToyiUIt+YhRlh4/1VJIjAstREiLnyfhoVXErn5BwpPDuERwhKEzUUqIwQm4/YEMvCh4yN3FsJKMBmT5hIjhIp5SDkkV+5DiUBnFgJjDAljpGXeQGBEwSAREWvhEeKQMBLzhnA1dGIE30T8uUg8EkVEh0g8hMNwPgLzxG3IyQhI8dhPER8QN0ZE0ZqHRK4TIwWYjDDM/DmI/7R27H7idmRYkcjuEOkVXP81DLHdmYiQYUVEgxTZDjtPAfl8boCsHbd2AEEViZCH4TBAFkzfPpIBciaCJEJ1xyVoNwmQFglbZF6ot3aTUB/FSGOIQJT37bIM9TORdowYKdJmxBPzkeVuZBMr49cRsXdFOzDPDSquYH4FjFfL2gVrmR5GBYyKRQ0WC3cG0mEF5OCiiQg3OA6ZfgeCAuNcB6T2BBbiEWKiPQMQxIzZSLADCNwFEGaGTLsNcUJeOO5dwDoqkbN8FVaP5xDA/A4Z+IQ1q+VwJvKs57rNjx73QlhaIKgwegdSOw4vYB29Kh6ETnOE+BAlAKlVBrMRv+O++mh3IJHIDxlbAIEl7qr5k1nIx9FspOO7r/72OAoFEwsgTOyOEPJqHBESORazERfC3t+WRBiys8UQ/wIWhqtXh8fEfRw6TvMYEJdQi0QQo4VtzkAeXyOGRKJbR9cxE4+MaSQeXQUTPX6FbkP+BhDBnkhEvxMhMdIv7Y4hFiIGIEY4u7kk8tt+qQ6hLpSIdmdzudMINJdDRA+aq3IL8uaNP0LonUgHph+++qL0jLjPPNNxHgJyRkRIgq1yOHN0ceT6EomGyN1D2L+gCeI4I8SVQzjYqg7mIB2JhPdAehewjl7RUhsQ302QjkTCfrUyc8bzqu+mCFsEEQWYjLCOXrFSz8UjxCeQcIX9Wrk3G+mduf/n/0Yw41np7rASmCgMz2EdlUiLdFzfcc5apu/LAPnwi1p1ZoBk/Ai7gwHVw5AbBTN4X7sDaYfRORwpDvVihISoiAGxiuZspEwA4SakQWYRB+/r35aVEXFY3u6NdDksmsINA4rP2iwwO+2ebzhvAk7M9iykqi+B2LyIJOKVsVFPkL7mXnnVvFGfMYSLe7Ny2LuQfLVZtcRZ79PH/MkFFa8b7ZdvKv7z/uOnpYsZCHkcLYEUC82aJcy2+5hDli6cxsuXb5j/3P2XV2FhXQgnhaZF+EfP3F0mCm+E8/Di5RULC/DtHEQsgVisae1y91ef/qBwVvijIBIRXxTEDwozkWKVLINEr6xd2fFHO0aBiWLp4uUrTKvi0c4MxD5GNWNJhEjk40+eAFL1H//O1RnjH38yE9HFyQpI37oKc5B3+nvP3UvG2PHsji+IwQqIS65Cm/GKX3juUFql4RzEWmZ0WY+2RshvIVxqgMDAiuYgxcpSQ/jRVm2IQFeUUfX5c0DCechyk/G4D5MRkN2r8K9gXexLxH/uz0FIYZmwsnPcr0rk0w+bpe0Y+XUTwsrnUXN2WCnoSyC2/wXkfTJA5o0TidSglnGvWnuzAyRxzCWQS/8LTSIBI2YHkDe8SBrOm1ZhVqh/d1ZGyou4wbiF9re0QEcCwxR42GkzYdg5qBchtWCMzBjCWog7J4KZoi4CcjVjo2sSKZg6q0kEAWIlyMuIa4BwI/QsRvGsDBIQNEJqtyMBk2tAzSI+rx6LYvEjiTx7GbFKFAn+pNe3aOTMSu6OzU8LUGUJBxaKu5HH/QorSgSKKhIju8/kLAaEhW2XBOGsDLJ2bJ7WrCFSvB15E0mkKRFYH4bI8ycp8swlb2Yi1q5EIjkGfHHVXAZplqDchCOEv3LJH+cilh/tRB84/9y6C7kKJfIqRYpVH/p095ljchwjEADZHORhw/Tpg2Pt1T5Ugrcjz/0EQd6W9UhHCfIfHVPoEdWEfxvysC5o52HuTQ8vhvRTRIeyjlsfPnYccSmRzq2IJ4T/kEGqctW/HSm4CZI0VyFGHj8mjqCyuc5C93vzEWZB1ccGdyMI/TkgXwyRsj5E5OiC8Dkf+UGJj5AvFkZq0PEjJB7CgsxtrtruDw5riyJMyOai6WQsPg7HEW7NR44lEvkPC298KDfvQmRYYWlYIQnyM+LwOKwISHnYnLDyg1JBUPfh9pseuWJ3IhAgAfFkgCS7EeJWoWo5XIPRxfRbAuSej3z24Lj+6mgBJAn1gECoJ8+GiGgkyPxQv+e3fb4TtZ09665Qr7ZsFaIQhShEIQpRyPJbtlaD4x58nUc17LgClaD4IrIyvX1vRetDRnMJ+c250Zq7vT1Ciho1AbHyqGycxYhXxp36XQiSiH2k43O9NXejfrQjsVMe+C9lReoPeoAQX3z64VkjR+9AqoeA5I8Fvhi4jN6FPGdh76Ws4/wwbMSIu+s2CsEdSE0iZFeYF5HL2N1ILxwiz2JEEFeWNoshDy/YAsgFL4kE8aME4eTsIf3jQki4IPIYkOeyIgXkIkZoLV/q3tXxVdnxjVDsSiS6a3RVYgQNEeTLnRC/t9AQbgU6IHePLjs5E6hIAXkeI9x67kcLDeHgSH8sEfOu5tqOkcIQiTv+pc/YIkOY74rHsrnCBTo+RBZUpIA0P0qQ32l3InHHCyhlJTJYZAgjCypSGML3RYhE6N0dLyejX7SgIgXEMdPJ6BcWRYrb0QIzPl8edIoWVKR+1HPO0rDi5xbqkyaUstuDu+eJDJAPLAIVqU8N5xNBPAwB0l8gQGq2BQGS5CBAsrtDPcsD8izyOXauJAKh3l8g1APSTUP9/Lp01qLFN7EybgR5mw3iXPGfILmAXnpGx85pnnD9k/UjNYlowt6PkRZxfZQBUnLldMrXrGdRJM6I2y+sHylKhMGyFSOO4/bnbyUvjTQlwq3NIDxBhNu31t9crxKkwa3HgLRhdJmZIDIwtCRCNc9y/fr6kX6CBLUYoTCEvUwQ2Vy8GDeXwK7P1t/xXySIKNZQvBXs+jwjhMEQjpFMhvDZJ3Q4GWvVGOl8unbE3WFJWGnWYsQl/tnaw0pLInGArFV5hUKA9My1B8igyiWiiy6PkUBQ0laFqUIUohCFZH/bEBKgLG/GBpF3p08U8jVFGlyHqsRscCxsQzBD2Pe+sncBhCILkBOJaDB1skECRIYIsjxkZYJ4CANST5AWIpkgLWamSCMgdYob6+14RKAGbVxyidgSYeSErR0p6ICcCGOIcGxwc81ISAeANERDIrUYMcXaEVkkbgYxRFsiRUDEA1Oi60VCBogZI79IEJwtks8aaSHzdITAlMwMebABpLERZCsrJB7CScc3TrPq+HHk51kh8uEVmIwnEvlNOhmNtSO6IGlYabSyCivCZCPEywiBGyBJqE+R9Yd6iWAjWbQaQUaLlkRMs1UdIZTYNAOEIzNJJBo0w0QC4SQlSpFsUiJEkuSuwTJM7lpCJGkqi9NUnk2aqkoHhShEId8g5PUm6vjXG6jjkbaBOt59vYE6Pny9gTr+7TWSXR3PfzxCMqzjnRGScYmdOXLdJxnW8ddIdnX82GTMro53J84kozo+vIFkUGK/nUayqOPHJmOGdfx/mur4TOr43jSSRR2PxyZjVnU8fZEiWdbxnRejEju7Ov7Fiw3U8aMzybKOH/ZJtnU83kQd39tEHf92E3V8bxN1PN5Awj2a8VneOptAXrwzZ7KRPtnI6LpeGbO8vd0A0thE9UutTTTXybvSJxvZkegaKcKIgOxOBAIKeegoiPPU5JgZMqtYFfnfP52LeDqH1VJ+vyry62GfUMJNGAXU0hhJEFvjGFbhbBGEOIZ8or5GJCDMhAV4iMAk1b0arlO8TsSTHT2OcDOoYcjx7DUiLRKYTBdshDBMizJbXQNiD6tfm3gmBaT4XWolCAHETHYP1jUZ/4xcmsGPJhDG1428T9pm0B5D4APPm1A6FldG/E6K7JCOObiBQPL9i9WR11+lSJW8Nr9sC76zdyQmkfzKyIu3k2FliNionCKn2SKoGCMPNoA01o+InerHU8jW+jp+iLxX/f6w41PkdPUh7M9HWIL8fGWE4rkIAURuTPxmfTN+iPxyiEBYiWOX3KJYN2LH8X4c8dYXVm4imMWhfg3IjdE1QmDRKspFS+4erHuejBBYfotYbkxkgFwKQ1BkxIlETSYScvcgO8RGcUqULZImd3L3YN0df43INJUb60BGYSXTIgirR0zvcfM20VzNTXS89dNNID97VxCyCaT51QaQyy/VBs4yGzhnlCHkITOANUTuQkPeReE7lD4g1NIFrMuiC6euiRYyRYCp1Q0oIgNx91LwdgppGWOIcY0gWGUs4cHygohEWkaCmIsgYgqxtTFEH0NIgIhEKMISsbUEMe6BvD37XwmChgi0h/z6GvEQFp7VCOBsAUEpov/nrxZG6C9/eQa/JYTRgoZPEesyiMcf3NoUt5gpEa9myJ8ZrRixTv7iL/5iYQTZpkQgpRtDvGuE40sOCGl4wkhSvwS5RN/V7hS0KQQHVoJ48H1wjQjzBI4OyCUMyIa8XzlGugsgr4cdrwckQWiKdKeRBnzp4UYbvpYITRHZfHfcPh8iRmAtifA7X9vgy+EFsIaXIKZI+6TdmETkNRTQho2TeEbC/ZI+6crxsGDH8w8+I8noGke644jM/bpmoxEjMgVMkN9W/9WiCPv+b5KG0saRyxuIMUS0FLn8xd6P7swg9fRMjn04E5hvNkmRRjue8eYk0hgiNpFzFebJq6p/5+gaJhJfCitGWsYYYtxAToYIxC6JIJ2Lz+/M6ivXoT5GPP3WM2kPEU9PEGOBDnnxsymEaSliduPYNYVcDhGmJYh5b6QrQ+E1MqPju0NEtNL15D5F0AgZhhUZZtPYRfUR4o2QNKyIpZB0xnOERpMxQQwIWt0AJuNljNDFkddfTSKjsHIDicNKNzCmwsp9K61FELoMMl5pJbErRRiBo9wI9YCkod68BzJeBCWxKxhDbixaXWYkixbcbwVE98Q1MjaEGW5VE6RoJPsVdGGkZk5ORtNGEmmhPYvtxYlEct1Smkh0uYw0cexCiyPVcAppaWOIPo7IlAgQSIni2KUtjlSiKSSJXSlijCFxctcVBiR3aexaGPnp2ymEmgnySPBcnKamiC6voZCIqCfD2lwOyey2EeTPN1FpBb7aW/lWItcXwGZ4e72JM/l8E8iXanTd5zZcGSFbFO9B7Ib62kYFEkCOB0uvGYf0B0i+7Tf2BCQwyDq5PzJcGRdAbCKR2hInPlwZGbF57nYE/gdIdYlLlYfryQ3EIyliBBJhKI9MhAJUXuKawmkkzqbZJGIyAj/ipilagaCFTBHcEJCH0SWuARiujHwaaeEphJGGOIG+WuKSieHKyPF71b1x5DdD5EeDIdKB3FQEAi89GW9BujHyfUbagDQCYa4PaZiTCKqSNjcDLUuEwrgGxEOrIOLBzl55JvKkd43gNSCQxQNiw6xG8jrrBDlox0hhRz586gVHtewQXsubOiMRLReyQ+AOSKcwAPbQCsjT4h4dQzhup8jHnQQxAbEEK6yC/EJeenPd8dfIUSNF7BgprhOBKmsK8doSISfrQ5hsuklEyHOLH71dGvntXORsfUjL0mYjZTMOK/B1JxAhfInXhiRbHtcIjAQHBnWb1moZIrU8BuSSljNEaCFvml3hBeUllt8R4omTFIkTCVhnj2TmIGgVJwGSIIkghrJDGLIQ7opAY8s9e2shhCNhk66gOl8uq52JdAV7NI6IupDbR1zuEarCVCHfVoRXGXlg8Rqk7n6XWmeZIIzRvEF41dSF3wpIRgiNPnlCWPXTD0Xn6gmevfrZR7e97czdSBSEV6FDK/2KaDRLzmzkxd+9XelMojehGzpfVPxIPGxazY9mI/9lReSPwu05/8/yB6LErXw2SMiE23C55beFz6sFdy5irYY4Z4C4HeEzVnGzOhPsA3IWCp+Kx3OQo/eN1RBOQkBwZEC3PJuN2F+ueiby3Te5RQAJxX+YPR1+vTLCBCDyDW99fy7yd6siEQOkyivCd33HzWQyhuwr9sTlP+MfCv91D2czuiIWPDAcXjYgQNpHJDPENCUCod4uW3OQ//FPVpqM8bvvOBkvWvF7z5B3AZHv4cCtjJHNJBKv//5t9oj7h6+yR/7+nUH+8A9fWptAsj+Tf9gI8o+fZ4/84zuDvP7xj98VxNkE8vpF5pNRVb/f1jreCO73WxSjlmfeE/nq8/uN4K9863Xtvmfy9vWL+yFfWq9/nTny1TLIiz/cH/nq3sjr7M/kq3sj6P4db9z/TFr8vohYorm+psgS8+Rritw3rHy+DBLcL+GGAPma33MyqkVrcSTbNyOK349oQ4jqeIUo5OuC0JLjHdSbxmk5v+2VDxqNunOaK1fofqnrnNZq2LmguUOjK1+Co35uKUQhClGIQhSiEIUoRCEK+fohqghSiELGb63k+RAIXV/vLREbHZa6F9SiRrO8ZflR1CxFwo/oQRQ5Ea9Z9XqzZkX9/ZwRebmt2vapIRqR0/XyW+WKcPy+/IGtORf+5pGxy20U8jVBWKYdnxx7Q8jkZPxmIl0hnFmId5i36KFGazmtr9Xhn7ftO/SAwjHtGra36/Yh2u7S7YbDNeFc1Lv1qF82eDm3n8+jQ7jHOIIw1aFPkBFoWSFoR746hER0T88MySHDQ3DgDwZuJzMETqElkQ/pmZshotkS2WPYyQ7BKEYKNUKyQ4h8LiFDRauWLcIlQpiV2TyRvcLlZMRUZIloMXI2mET6BzaGKEK38ihXuahTdFjOobLW3Kqhbe9A/qBEjX7lwsN8u+tp59Y59rt9g5bRQX+7YRvTSBy7Or1skezPxOKz+2S9iBiOLvniVhkhEIeTecKt/5oV4mGE9uIZb5G/yQxBKI1dxPnXWSFBGiA/pPgsszOhaaj/YHDWyexMWLxoxcuKPtHx3nZfi5pWxK1THNmHeXTgNHEkLhw4Zl2cVkSj28zh6HxL41aj69fpttOtdx2K66f5rQqdCCscll8tfvza09rZIPKAhBnTRdDakVmV1jcX4domziS3CaTwziB/+Z72Tx/krGyRf/bvP/n5v/mfk8ih5lXOZSKBDg2ZN+yXTi2qnee29iGG2Jbf3z80GtTqb9Wsc8O3D7p8fzuKor7Ga9t1bt1EjP/+/Jdvskb+Rfv58588Etkif9l7/nwrl/GZFAERT0m2SOHyefPfdTJGchefNP9tO1uEQ4ZnvP/djPtk7OllWSJnm0DMmwiyLrq0vFVG5e04b/DwBc2XtX7e8Ovn+zm0r3Xr5zJvOISl2y7ZtYMmylfOsb0Ff0d3sUVLIX8iZOJyRKIQhZS6TcPb5rjRPKAl0fAhrNTK+9s0h5vbPG9AUtH1ueWcH2p2vuRwq97Ma/F+ofyVrdq+pRCFvEvI6AFi+q4i3rbPywavHULugBtdL39Y1nhOu2jwbW5E56hC97f293Pb9S7c7dywD+rdPkSU3AE1mlqzJP4ECEs2JBSiEIXcH+mX82hbQLQo0X3jHDexbxv1C5km7Gv1qO6coxLPl3Pa+Va+5EOO0fUMb2s/V3EcuqU1Nf/dRcxZsUshCvmmIzWjTg270oRUwTqt4brv7Vfix/i3KnVxWi7j7mnNoqVTCD37cN/TvOGV/HrklbfymtPX5iJXeAPI78wNIP/N3QByebYBhDobQDYyuroZ9om8YYm0MkZMibwyN4B0zPHSQetSCBv9/D5u2FAd7OPTfHlfO8+jwy3tdB93+/vYp6W6w+UPztEh9nAUXTh2iW97NWsu4rsbQCaLoG8y0jLfFcTfRHOF70zHByQ7ZBQgWxNhZQsSCSj8y1tGvWHj/kHfsnNl3N/CzX3D3rbL8qr4yDO6/Tw6gD8Dag0vV67UaW5rq4ZKcxHX3QCykTMJ8AaQyZUxI6S/iTP57Sb65OqdGV3epkeXV+L7MltoVrocNxoNCCB1Z5RZ1Jv7VpxZiCY+3fYbot7PGf280Y1OjQYvccv50yLjffLNRvxNNFf4Te/4+BavJ5tAWptArsxNNNc4sk1rOZk3yCt3ncjLH9CycQ7RJI9PNSe9lLdBDVo+3BZeybacfryBeAilhOY4C/ZJVojYBDKed2WGtDbSJ+67cibjedd6kbkPN2WEdN0NIOM7Ev6Fh2mt5MWX8sIxo/5+DeW0c8gkSrbR8IzmAdX88xqq9LGdr0z8IF/yjLnI+I5EZkhnE4ifVXPNe4D5m420zHcF8TfRXOGmO96rnGrxI/h57PiOE/negd+luJnbykN+YZcrXomWc2XL8U+N/r7lON2GZzX3K406rUEIwnORiZUxK2RiPckKmVgZv9FnMrEyZoVkNLomb113A0hrE8grcwNIZyLv4rWy5df78eZgX/O7kV3LVbh2WrIrouF4JQgn+ILv4z4qgeB7FXnpvnwosF/ycDQX8d0NIJN5V0ZIdxNn0toE8moTHa9G19cPmVxPbHyOageQP1jd8wrF/jmkFOjQOM1pfaupNei+4dcvhF3q7+fzuFkua155a7+8FT+GoP2JkYn9rqyQcBOI2ATSwu9Kxwt3E8hGzgRvenQdOF2ag9iC693oossxJBINWjugcMS+dW7YtYOufPK9B993G93zA+H4Dbhr3/BqUEEYClGIQr5JCGQF25GNm1uHmnDqfpcfRHVe6aP8FiQT0SnK75ccL1/xDuwthC/qzf1t4W07vHxgl3iJag2FKEQh3xREvSygQhSiEIUoRCEKUYhCFKIQhShEIQpRiEIUohCFKEQhClGIQhSi3nVdjS6FKEQhClGIQhSiEIUoRCEKUci3EWGC62tHGNJaj94zbCv9viVofDRdBO+1EJZfcmQ2RGONCEfJy1QwJFpohOgnwlgv4lEiXwXDsq8RbVWkPBjwIknfF1PwnOhxQIIyMbzOWYyITrfL8RoRQROky/OYjpDAY1kgPZEn1whdOxJQ6J+2eH8CKa8bkaOrIz6xxDXyWWUlJD5qgiA9/jaeJzEyfAeqTvDZh2tGrs9khHR7+roROo209NWRqT7pMjKNGL3GmpF4CMPoGkNwz80CkfMkGvWJWAuCezNmfDCGiNURYpxMTcY4dq0Psc3WI9MevZkoMuIhLKOwlqwsEIWJXTZWR1rX78lmxIeW64m+ZkS+MswQSZZfWBnN9SEqJVLItwkJNFSmIckc2RtkjQicz20AwbneZxtAOn0re+TMxtn3iZk9gvaMuLlsZNWFOJHrQkC4ITwL6iQooZgp6iIgKyJ0hMAKesI0ITxMNWETKGHgY6BzZLXwakiOPomby0ZVRES8eLbMAAmolwxY3rCnMVjjzNWQnXJvhGChy4TAlmkBMrlEzBaiCNvGih2/1/tt0lxlhLnuwenYhodqyGQGZAYJglZGBlfxtx7dMQE5gjbTvaDwwKCAPDDq3hF8PadKb6E90/bkn9FCJPhAfEcOkO8QaOyjP0O6rV3PkxTpBkWT6bKKNU4uaQEbniEoNurBUfGBeXIrsocMQFo6ky9xBh+GCDT9EKEJchlYJk2RNiC4BQhpnARHtQfm2a1IDumA2Hr8CqPwAXo0QcgQ+WWKtIcINy9DWiDiMkZ6QbX2YN4IppB191gN4zaFrLUdVGWdXSWB1eb4rDdgZHrROgksI0gRQfeIaEvkRAQWf38+QnCHWSbuyq96A5l1w4fPCOTfgNys4xsSgcaxJBIA0lkIOTtj1hkezERuJtwGIN4JzBCJeOVH1usE8Sz2fm5OWKGfkQ5OkM8IDgdCIgJ+NmDW0w9mIkWjewIzXiKIfk/OeIp14Qm28905M572xGdEIl34yoCTlostVNmmRMjN5uIm3THaMnZJBAoAU8h5osttpp15k5FChm3JPjmBr2xC9eRnZ2eUwrcDStKnrqdvKCERBEh6JnqKQG0LMbhwC0IFjC4oHeCvMViyH2WddWIkSOfJi+TOnwOCGTIawz6BSWzEATJF9NvOBCYGll/pIn69QSRH3McSSWf8NcIkYpxAWImR8oMhAr1SnRdWkj6BuUfgK/hzqByGFCMdkKewStxEuGaYJ+k8Cfagy6GN0AnE4hYz6/MQDKNLE3lMe3lr4MsXCfJFHpDvi6cfDro3EXGyZZ5cAiYnY47IfTdxeQKx2Gb4cl59iuU8EdikUF0PZCUq62yk8Q/E2WAQpAit4UYkEbm9t4XQXycISxFxQk2h3YbIGS9wYxzZsQawigNC044PCqZ+KxLAInMLkofYBUgbvjIv5S6a8NiOReF3AUlj14uw0NkdDJEHQyRkOynS8Agz+DykhSDX8XSIqz9E0BNyxRMegrqYwHDW7GJSmL7wL/qVboLwYoLIUD9EYFWxmHk3EkgEFlRLIkeAnEmEjCEvE4RK5IcUx4vWTjy6GDZgwsO51e9A6A8RfoRDmBgi1IIR0kgRp1/5vUQCC5ZfcTK2/MZhxbiU5zhvniy2xsdIlCAMspWTYSJRTGe8aaMjZKJVkVfXCBEnw5SoFscuyLsSxFgReTpE+BBJkjsznvEYoX1k2qsi+SEirtNUdp2mxshqaSogxREiE24xlnAbMuGOkdUS7hd+s5YgGZYOL/znPHsk/CuxmzkS7Bl65ggtG43MkdGipZCvC3Kd3KlNNYUoRCEKUYhCFKIQhShEIQr5WiIBwsKzOEJWC8V7NdkgprBxghAudyQzQpCZIvHDaNk0F0dG2lxUXqSaBSIEM3WOqdWGbwpmZghpcxzEiMgMoaQrSCAA8eRj7RkhVld+BqSbJTKQJxEjnWwQG5BAHv83OnxoZzSECbU8ibQQfDjJap5Q+b61l4AApmc14xmx5fWj8vF5nhFSNJiJYoTioJANQkUDYorcKO/BtEd6RuvJiZBIQz4CyzJD2sL+bowICMY/ygzx9kX8kJsp6ieZITA/ZGSU/78OK8lTE4af1oBcjhBjiARIG/skWPzCDDDM5ed4fNjJJRyLIyfQ6THCR6EeDmddf4oR+YhTisgHuyUy9galt916soV0wbE4g/+zEQIHw9efEgQvi1xyg5UNiRgUD4ZvUi94svXMhjvQLNmLXhJpIVNekiCfSIGIN0ok0j6g8EkfIcYNxEveo/CumycRAkuw7EkPDfOu9OjyVT60EaIvi8hQj+Q6L0O9pw+R9OjeBKKNEHQ/hKP4aU7cii/RMMcRlA7ZmQiPkday0wglrRgf3U5GboqgLBArY6SVHH30JpcJYk0j9rIPsaRIkoDLZ1gliCXiCwRaycC21oJoctzJi2C8uEUkEowjbA2Ircvr1xjMPzpC4qvaJhG07CPyCSKvSsLyogIW/7ESYWtHTHn5gPzb+a3I99aByMpriPBrxCbsO/Ef8D19ZSTu6rhFbiB0PYiQSNI9GSK6uAth6EhfbXTJMCkjcIvchmirzRMZweQhOmKEjCZjC9Ot1ZFW/MveqDGSITyGBBKhiGqrxa7FELQSYt5A4gOuF9FuIMFNRGP3QewQFlzTRsPrhT00HErXSNxPCeKZwQO4Q6CxxXKi9BjflwgaR4xJJE0phoh3fwSSnEkkiA85heg3EJ3fAwkS5Lq5aLzsTiHGNOLpfLGcKEnxLC1gxAwEHUPwNGKuhlyKy0kkSVNbcumKW4kNM4oECQwvf2+kPY3wJCudRMwxpJVPmvMeOdHJNCIzLm0a0VdDGqKXIGysCELTiLYaAr8ZI0xcl3Myl5tE0DQCq849nrgB94wYceJnhA6f3DgDGQVIarSKyyCyehhDZHuR+YhuL4bIK8DlBaBdco2M7QvTKcRKipEJZGIq3YrYsxFI3HBLH0foEkhn8NwXgjh5iUAYn0a8aYTLkTSJoLtSyCFCJAIZ+zQCSbA3D2G6XYuTfnTHNbDt7k1krONlfhovWt4QEWOIhhZDXr5MEDmbhs01joibiLkEIqceceJNKNGNkdFklFedAqJNIPYUMgoD829XFwx+jTiteMYnyHCNj4OrvUZEPnGjcQPB8pjBPIRriC+EvHqcNJd8msvJHATNQ5BE6DCg3Yk0LRIvWtkgbkUiOC+RlqUJO/6XdrwcSLYZF0GrIZFEnhaL8R6JJvdUERpHkq2dW5BgGDXn37TWvpxcNXmvQL4o6wRiJIi8x4x5IpAmES39D3chHv/r+BjmVHPFF8/HlS9aBZlMU62p+kRLSuzkWTM3YleCeDGyeLpyowhCMkByJDcm9FHpMI3o6bRdGiFyByjeW9FHWf2akVaSzKFhCGTD/aIUsWVa19LTGbUaYt+OGEtvgY9vqrWGa99UIrEeJBhDzHlIXIcvtxk1vtHpoXSLeyq5G0Ps5RGaBPFgYntQG0MMnj7tdwWEJR3OJrZsrxNu+ARI3FLLPQdlVDoYySdtRqW1HkQOXjN51MGYUWmlCBbiruzuVqSVFlbJp+lKK0aKCaIvjwRoOADEWB9dI+Y6kOH4t7O5gF9dgaMQhShEIQpRiEIUohCFKEQh2SHex1QPCB5QXG+xj1s6J7ot//Xg41nLqxk9+EmAemdU58bOAwN+AvfX6/H9TXkH7wjusIfrlJnyn/7UUIhCFKIQhShEIQpRiEIUohCFKEQhClGIQhSiEIUoRCEKUYhCFKIQhShEIQpRiEIUohCFKEQhClGIQhSiEIUoRCEKUYhCFKIQhShEIQpRiEIUohCFKEQhClGIQpZH1AuIKEQhClGIQhSiEIV845H/D5MJR+NGNjvOAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample image?

Comment: yes Im sorry, I meant to type the other way around.

Comment: I would suggest you to take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502610/how-to-create-a-base64encoded-string-from-image-resource).
I solved my issue with it.

Answer (score 5):

You can also do the rotation in the browser thanks to css3 `transform` property:

```
#yourimage {
   transform: rotate(90deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

See support for this property [**here**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d), basically all browsers and IE9 onwards.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have Imagick installed on your server?  If so, the following should work...

```
$imagick = new Imagick(); 
$imagick->readImage($file);
$imagick->rotateImage(new ImagickPixel(),90);
header('Content-type: image/jpg'); //or whatever the image file is, set headers...
echo $imagick;
$imagick->clear(); 
$imagick->destroy();
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just saving the image, rotating it, displaying it in the browser, and then finally deleting it.

```
$label = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($image));

$rotated_imaged = imagerotate($label, 90, 0);
imagepng($rotated_imaged, '/var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/labels/fedex-test.png');
unlink('/var/www/vhosts/website.com/httpdocs/labels/fedex-test.png');
```

Thanks All

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which explicitly stated "without saving it to the disk" as a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps. Create a file just to output the image

```
<?php // image.php

header('Content-type: image/png');

// get $image string from API or wherever you've stored it

$res = imagecreatefromstring($image);

if ($res === false) exit;

$rotated = imagerotate($res, 90, 0);
imagedestroy($res);


imagepng($rotated);
imagedestroy($rotated);
exit;
```

Then include it as your `<img>` tag source, eg

```
<img src="image.php">
```

Example here - http://codepad.viper-7.com/nMIu7J

Comment: Thanks for answering, when I try your solution I get a Image corrupt or truncated error!

Comment: @DanielAdarve I forgot to add `base64_decode()` initially. Have you got that in your code?

Comment: I do, the image still comes out as corrupt

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `imagepng()` *either* sends the PNG it generates to a file *or* it sends it to the browser.  There isn't an option to store it in a variable instead.  So to do what you want without saving a file, you need to have your PHP script generate the image on-the-fly, perhaps from a base64-encoded `GET` variable.

Consider two scripts, let's call them `wrap.php` and `rotate.php`.

**wrap.php** might look something like this:

```
<?php

  // Pixel Art from Star Wars http://www.pixeljoint.com/pixelart/1423.htm
  $image = "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";

  $fmt='%1$s:<img src="rotate.php?angle=%2$d&orig=%3$s" alt="%1$s" /><br/>' . "\n";

  printf( $fmt, "Original",  0, urlencode($image) );
  printf( $fmt, "Rotated",  90, urlencode($image) );

?>
```

And **rotate.php**:

```
<?php

  $angle = (int)$_GET['angle'];      // Force this to be an int
  $orig = $_GET['orig'];  // We could do input validation on this, but meh.

  $ih = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($orig));

  $rotated = imagerotate($ih, $angle, 0);

  header("Content-Type: image/png");
  imagepng($rotated);

?>
```

By separating HTML-generation and PNG-generation into two separate PHP scripts, your original request to avoid generating on-disk temporary files is achieved.