# How to upload a file in one webservice call with Symfony2?

Tags: php, web-services, api, symfony, restful-architecture

In my Restful API, i want to upload a file in one call.
In my tests, the form is initialized and binded at the same time, but all my data fields form are empty and the result is an empty record in my database.

If I pass by the form view and then submit it, all is fine but i want to call the Webservice in one call. The webservice is destinated to be consumed by a backbone app.

Thanks for your help.

My Test:

```
$client = static::createClient();
$photo = new UploadedFile(
        '/Userdirectory/test.jpg',
        'photo.jpg',
        'image/jpeg',
        14415
);
$crawler = $client->request('POST', '/ws/upload/mydirectory', array(), array('form[file]' => $photo), array('Content-Type'=>'multipart/formdata'));
```

There is my controller action:

```
public function uploadAction(Request $request, $directory, $_format)
{
    $document = new Media();
    $document->setDirectory($directory);
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($document, array('csrf_protection' => false))
        /*->add('directory', 'hidden', array(
             'data' => $directory
        ))*/
        ->add('file')
        ->getForm()
    ;
    if ($this->getRequest()->isMethod('POST')) {

        $form->bind($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($document);
            $em->flush();
            if($document->getId() !== '')
                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('media_show', array('id'=>$document->getId(), 'format'=>$_format)));
        }else{
            $response = new Response(serialize($form->getErrors()), 406);
            return $response;
        }
   }

    return array('form' => $form->createView());
}
```

My Media Entity:

```
    <?php

    namespace MyRestBundle\RestBundle\Entity;
    use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizableInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizerInterface;
    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
     */
    class Media
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
         */
        protected $path;

        public $directory;

        /**
         * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
         */
        public $file;

        /**
         * @see \Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\NormalizableInterface
         */
        function normalize(NormalizerInterface $normalizer, $format= null)
        {
            return array(
                'path' => $this->getPath()
            );
        }

        /**
         * @see
         */
        function denormalize(NormalizerInterface $normalizer, $data, $format = null)
        {
            if (isset($data['path']))
            {
                $this->setPath($data['path']);
            }
        }

        protected function getAbsolutePath()
        {
            return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
        }

        protected function getWebPath()
        {
            return null === $this->path ? null : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
        }

        protected function getUploadRootDir()
        {
            // the absolute directory path where uploaded documents should be saved
            return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
        }

        protected function getUploadDir()
        {
            // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
            return 'uploads/'.(null === $this->directory ? 'documents' : $this->directory);
        }

        /**
         * @ORM\PrePersist()
         * @ORM\PreUpdate()
         */
        public function preUpload()
        {
            if (null !== $this->file) {
                // do whatever you want to generate a unique name
                $this->path = $this->getUploadDir().'/'.sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)).'.'.$this->file->guessExtension();
            }
        }

        /**
         * @ORM\PostPersist()
         * @ORM\PostUpdate()
         */
        public function upload()
        {
            if (null === $this->file) {
                return;
            }

            // if there is an error when moving the file, an exception will
            // be automatically thrown by move(). This will properly prevent
            // the entity from being persisted to the database on error
            $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->path);

            unset($this->file);
        }

        /**
         * @ORM\PostRemove()
         */
        public function removeUpload()
        {
            if ($file = $this->getAbsolutePath()) {
                unlink($file);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Set Directory
         *
         * @param string $directory
         * @return Media
         */
        public function setDirectory($directory)
        {
            $this->directory = $directory;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Set Path
         *
         * @param string $path
         * @return Media
         */
        public function setPath($path)
        {
            $this->path = $path;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get path
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getPath()
        {
            $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
            return $request->getHost().'/'.$this->path;
        }

        /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return string
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }
    }
```

My routing:

```
upload_dir_media:
  pattern:      /upload/{directory}.{_format}
  defaults:     { _controller: MyRestBundle:Media:upload, _format: html }
  requirements: { _method: POST }
```

Comment: aren't there supposed to be curly brackets at 
if($document->getId() !== '')

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking this problem down into a simple state. How would you post 'text' or a variable to a web service with one post? Because an image is just a long string. Check out the php function [imagecreatefromstring](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php) or [imgtostring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502610/how-to-create-a-base64encoded-string-from-image-resource) . This is often what goes on behind the scenes of you image transfer protocols.. Once you so solve the simpler problem, you will have proven you can solve your original problem.