# How to achieve the reverse effect of imagecreatefromstring in PHP?

Tags: php, image, php-gd

How can I get a base64 string from an image resource in PHP? Note however, I made the image on the fly, so no URL exists.

Here is what I've tried, but it doesn't work:

```
echo 'data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($img);
```

This gives an error:

```
Warning: base64_encode() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create a base64encoded string from image resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502610/how-to-create-a-base64encoded-string-from-image-resource)

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8502656/2959229)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no way to tell GD to return your image as a binary string, unfortunately.  GD only supports writing to a file or to the screen.  What we can do though is use output buffering to capture its output and then put it in a string.

```
ob_start();
imagepng($img);
$image = ob_get_clean();

echo 'data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode($image);
```