# How to resize/crop or reduce the size of an image displayed from SQL Server query?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, image

I want to minimize the size of a SQL Server image before it gets loaded on the clients.

Unfortunately I get the example not implemented:
[Resizing and then displaying BLOB element from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21709098/resizing-and-then-displaying-blob-element-from-database)

Code:

```
<?php
include "dbconf2.php";

$sqlimage="
SELECT
        F.Grafik,
        F.knr,
        F.brstatus1,
        F.untertitel1,
        F.anzeigeweb1

    FROM FOTO F 
    WHERE F.knr LIKE 'FHTG20900%'
;";

$stmtimage = sqlsrv_query($connVHS, $sqlimage);

while ($result2=sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmtimage)) {

            echo "titel: ".$result2['untertitel1']."<br>";
            echo "knr: ".$result2['knr']."<br>";
            echo "status: ".$result2['brstatus1']."<br>";
            echo "web: ".$result2['anzeigeweb1']."<br>";
            echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $result2['Grafik']).'" style="max-height: 500px; max-width: 400px;"/>'."<br>";
            echo "<br>";

}
?>
```

Edit: my simple implementation:

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring(base64_encode( $result2['Grafik']));
$image = imagescale($image, 100, 100);

ob_start();
imagejpeg($image);
$contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo "<img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($contents)."' />";
imagedestroy($image);
```

but I get these errors:

> Warning: imagecreatefromstring(): Data is not in a recognized format ...
>
> Warning: imagescale() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in ...
>
> Warning: imagedestroy() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in ...

Comment: _“This solution doesn´t help”_ - saying this solution doesn’t help without saying _why/how_ it does not help, does not help either. Please go read [ask].

Comment: Sorry, I´m not a pro and don´t get to work ... :-/

Comment: Well then you still need to show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you,but you have to first create an actual image from SQL.
It's better if you can save image file as actual file.It is far more faster.

```
function resize_image($filename, $tmpname, $xmax, $ymax)  
{  
$ext = explode(".", $filename);  
$ext = $ext[count($ext)-1];  

if($ext == "jpg" || $ext == "jpeg")  
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($tmpname);  
elseif($ext == "png")  
    $im = imagecreatefrompng($tmpname);  
elseif($ext == "gif")  
    $im = imagecreatefromgif($tmpname);  

$x = imagesx($im);  
$y = imagesy($im);  

if($x <= $xmax && $y <= $ymax)  
    return $im;  

if($x >= $y) {  
    $newx = $xmax;  
    $newy = $newx * $y / $x;  
}  
else {  
    $newy = $ymax;  
    $newx = $x / $y * $newy;  
}  

$im2 = imagecreatetruecolor($newx, $newy);  
imagecopyresized($im2, $im, 0, 0, 0, 0, floor($newx), floor($newy), $x, $y);  
return $im2;   
}
```

Comment: I need a solution without saving, (it´s an internal project, not public www)