# ERROR rotate image with php

Tags: php, html

Hello I'm trying to rotate an image with php as follows, I get the image in base64 and rotaciono, but when I try to turn it again into a base64 error as I do that emerges?

```
$img64=$_POST['IMG'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img64);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$source     = imagecreatefromstring($data);
$rotate     = imagerotate($source, 90, 0); // if want to rotate the image

$data = base64_encode($rotate);//ERROR
```

Error:

```
<b>Warning</b>:  base64_encode() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in <b>C:\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\data\localweb\projects\STEP\php\rotateLand.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
```

Comment: would it hurt to use jquery to rotate the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to pass an image object to base64_encode, which only takes a string as a parameter.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502610/how-to-create-a-base64encoded-string-from-image-resource) regarding converting an image object to a string for base64 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

`$rotate` isn't a string; it's an image resource. Unfortunately there's no easy way to turn it into a string - you have to use output buffering. Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8502656/2765666).

Answer (score 0):

Grateful for help, my code looked like this. problem solved

```
$img64  = $_POST['IMG'];
$img    = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img64);
$img    = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data   = base64_decode($img);
$source = imagecreatefromstring($data);
$rotate = imagerotate($source, $_POST['rot'], 0);

ob_start();
imagejpeg($rotate);
$contents =  ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo $rotate = base64_encode($contents);?>
```