# how can compress the uploaded image, convert into base 64 and directly store in database using laravel

Tags: laravel, base64, compression

I want to compress the uploaded image and store the base64 of the image in the database. Every time I google the question I always gets the idea to use the image stored in a certain path. I'm using `intervention/image` package

I have tried this code

```
$img = Image::make($request->photo)->resize(300, 200);
//get the extension
$type = $request->file('photo')->getClientOriginalExtension();
//convert it into the base64.
$base64 = 'data:image/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode(file_get_contents($img));
```

I want to store the photo in the database after compressing and converting into the base64 format. [Error that I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4f1w.png)

Comment: Check it once again the content is 100% different, And remove the flag.

Comment: You have an error `$img is empty`, where did you fill `$img` you provided for your `file_get_content()` ?  `base64_encode(file_get_contents($img));`

Comment: $img is in first line of the code section.

Comment: `file_get_content()` accepts a path/filename not an instance of `Image`

Comment: Duplicate of this then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502610/how-to-create-a-base64encoded-string-from-image-resource

Comment: No bro, Review the question properly and remove the duplicate tag. he already has the base64 code for the image. But I want to compress and covert the uploaded image directly,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need not write any compression or conversion code. 
Try adding `encode('data-url')`

I hope it works.

```
$img = Image::make($request->photo)->resize(300, 200)->encode('data-url');
```